# Trying to simplify $A'B'C'D + A'B'CD + A'BC'D + AB'CD + ABCD$

Tags: boolean-algebra

My solution so far:

$A'(B'C'D + B'CD + BC'D) + A(B'CD + BCD)$

$= A'(C'D(B' + B) + B'CD) + A(CD(B'+B))$

$= A'(C'D(1) + B'CD) + A(CD(1))$

$= A'C'D + A'B'CD + ACD$

$= D(A'C' + AC) + A'B'CD$

$= D(A\text{ xnor }C) + A'B'CD$

$= D[(A\text{ xnor }C) + A'B'C]\text{ <<< Can't seem to get any further than this.}$

Did I perhaps screw up somewhere? Or not do it as well as I could have? Maybe missed using a rule?

Thanks!

K

Comment: Is the expression supposed to simplify further?  Your steps appear correct up to your last expression...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start by plotting the Karnaugh map.

$A′B′C′D+A′B′CD+A′BC′D+AB′CD+ABCD$ is an sum of five minterms, thus the Karnaugh map will show five ones (I've left out zeroes for greater visual contrast):

$$
\begin{matrix}
     & A'B' & A'B & AB & AB' \\
C'D' &                       \\
C'D  &  1   &  1             \\
CD   &  1   &     &  1 &  1  \\
CD'  &
\end{matrix}
$$

This can be covered as a sum of three products, of which two are essential, in two ways.

$$
F = A'C'D + ACD + B'CD = ((A\ xnor\ C) + B'C)D \\
F = A'C'D + ACD + A'B'D = ((A\ xnor\ C) + A'B')D
$$

Which are both one term shorter than your original: $((A\ xnor\ C) + A'B'C)D$. Note how you used disjoint terms as a covering for the function. This often happens when you simplify as expression without looking at the Karnaugh map.

---

Starting from the same Karnaugh map, you can also choose to start with a product of sums. As a product of three sums, all essential:

$$
F = D(A'+C)(A+B'+C')
$$

Or if you prefer, an inverted sum of products:

$$ F = not(D'+AC'+A'BC) $$

Answer (score -1):

It simplifies to $[(A+B)'C+A' + B'D +BD]'$.